# How can I calculate in advance the Uber fare from CDG to Paris?

Tags: airport-transfer, paris, fares, cdg, uber

Before I summon an Uber, is there a way to know, more or less, how much it would it cost to go from Charles de Gaulle Airport to Montmarte Paris's 18th arrondissement?

Comment: Uber has a a fare estimator. It says 45 Euros for UberX. Do you not trust the estimator ?

Answer (score 5):

There is a fixed fare from CDG to Paris right bank of the Seine. It is 45 € with Uber X, not less not more. This won't fluctuate if there is a traffic jam or if it takes 2 hours...

Answer (score 2):

You can view the estimated fare on the app just before confirming the booking:

[image]

Alternatively you can use one of the many fare estimator websites out there, including [uber's own one](https://www.uber.com/en-FR/fare-estimate/) which says that the fare is 45 EUR with UserX or Green:

[image]

As it turns out, this is to date [the flat fare from CDG into Paris](https://www.uber.com/airports/cdg/).